# Getting this error while trying to find aws cdk versiom

Tags: aws-cdk

```
C:\Users\Administrator>npm install -g aws-cdk

removed 7 packages, changed 192 packages, and audited 199 packages in 26s

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

// Here I check if it is intalled
C:\Users\Administrator>cdk
Usage:
cdk [-vbo] [--toc] [--notransition] [--logo=] [--theme=] [--custom-css=] FILE
cdk --install-theme=
cdk --default-theme=
cdk --generate=

```
C:\Users\Administrator>cdk version
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\cdk\data\asciidoc-8.6.8\asciidoc.py", line 101
    except KeyError, k: raise AttributeError, k
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
b''

C:\Users\Administrator>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would try using these 2 commands

```
npm install -g aws-cdk@latest

cdk --version
```